# What am i doing wrong in this loop

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 5

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int rooms[ROWS][COLS] = {0}, selection, building, room;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if(rooms[i][j] == 0)
            {
                rooms[i][j] = 1;
                printf("\nBuilding[%.2d]|Room[%.2d]: Reservation Succesfull.\n\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is not the full code and i only have a problem with this part.

What i want here is to check the first 0 that comes first and turn it into a 1. This will happen until all the 0 become 1 or until the user exits the program. I already made a "do while" for that. My problem is that when i run this part of the program it puts 1 both on ROWS 0 and ROWS 1 at the same time. I'm looking for why is this happening more than an answer to fix the program.

I made some tests like putting another if for the first loop(i) but that either resulted in the same problem or the whole ROWS 1 was skipped and only the ROWS 0 was filled.

Comment: `break` breaks out only one level of loop, but you have a 2-level nested loop.

Comment: Ideal solution is to wrap the two for-loops in a function, so you can `return` instead of `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the break statement just gets out of the first outer loop, it seems like you also want to skip the other outer one. You may need to add a flag to check only one 0 element will be changed to 1, or just change break into return to get out of the function as it is said on the comments.

```
    int flag = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if(rooms[i][j] == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                rooms[i][j] = 1;
                printf("\nBuilding[%.2d]|Room[%.2d]: Reservation Succesfull.\n\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Or with a clear explicit initialization of the matrix,

```
void func(void)
{
    unsigned int rooms[ROWS][COLS] = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    }, selection, building, room;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if(rooms[i][j] == 0)
            {
                rooms[i][j] = 1;
                printf("\nBuilding[%.2d]|Room[%.2d]: Reservation Succesfull.\n\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. My thought proccess was wrong i tried to do the "if" for the i loop without a flag but as an array element, making it check back on itself. If that makes sense.